# UTC Datastore different than UTC GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I have to run some batches in Google App Engine and some records are updated and some aren't. I log all the operations in a bigquery table and the updated records are in datastore. To better understand what I mean, here is my code:

Here is the entity:

```
class User(ndb.Model):     
  modified = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=true)
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Here is the command to get the current time to record the log in BigQuery:

```
date = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
```

After analyzing some records I found a difference of 1 hour between the  record in BigQuery and  the entity in Datastore. How could I be guaranteed that the time zone is the same for both? Thanks

Comment: You should post a full working example on the Issue tracer https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/entry